# How to do update data from API server in Android Kotlin daily between 1:00 and 1:59 Clock?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, background-service

Hy everybody,

I try now to create a Background-Service to update data on my app from api server daily between 1:00 and 1:59 with Kotlin android, but realy I haven't any idea how to do this, and which tool should i use for it?

If anyone know how to do this?, that would be very cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for background tasks you should study Job Scheduler in Android.
You can set constraint like if Network available, timings and other.

Read about Job scheduler from this android doc:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler

You can also see a codelab here:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-job-scheduler/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#0

Comment: Do you know, what about `Doze` mode in android?, would this every day working without stoping it from android `Doze` mode?

Comment: That's why Job Schedulers are for, to work with constraints like this

Comment: A periodic job can't be exact. A job is either exact or periodic. Periodic jobs are always inexact. That's simply the way how Android optimise for longer battery life.

Comment: but you can fire a job everyday at 4.00 PM for example.
If it is not exact the 4.00 PM but can be 4.15 PM or some here and there. Job scheduler will manage itself according to priority and preference. and as you need to use internet, you can also add this in constraint that only if net is available.